# How to create a Fallback answer when user doesn't provide a parameter in the right format in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an intent in Dialogflow where user needs to provide a parameter in a specific format of a entity that I have created (entity has a regex format). I would like to have a fallback answer ifn user provide the paramater in the wrong format. I've tried to create a followup fallback for the intent but the fallback intent is not triggered.
What I'm doing wrong[this is the parameter user need to enter which I want to have a fallback message if it's not in the right format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hsD1.png)

Comment: Is see that you made the entity required and added a prompt to ask the user another question in case they say nothing at all, does that work?

Comment: Hi Jordi, Yes, the bot ask the user to provide the order number but I want the bot to reply with something like "The format entered is not correct..." in case he provides the order number in the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as you mentioned in the comments, you already have a prompt set for when the user doesn't mention an order number at all. If the user inputs an ordernumber and it doesn't match the regex, Dialogflow will not detect a matching entity and because of that no entity is found in the user input. So even if just 1 character is off, it is handled in the same way as it not being mentioned at all.

Depending on the product that you use you might have a second option if you include a [webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-overview). I'm not completely sure if Dialogflow supports this, but if your product numbers consist  of a consistent structure, for example AB0000, you could try and create a regex that looks for a entity that consist of 2 letters and 4 numbers. This will then be detected as valid even when someone mentions ZY9999.

In your webhook you can then keep a collection of regexes that are considered valid productnumbers. You then run the code ZY9999 against those regexes and if the regexes say it is valid you know the product is valid. If those product regexes say its invalid then you create a new response telling the user that they need to input something else. It will be difficult to tell what exactly is wrong with the number, but its better than repeating "Did you enter a number?" over and over again.